# What does "deadly" mean in the phrase "deadly secrets"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, listening

In this [audio file](http://ilielearning-sd.ir/content/lessons/11/Intermediate1_2/unit%207/listening/listening.mp3), at 0:55, what does *deadly* mean?

1. Causing or likely to cause death
2. Complete

The textbook says 1, but I think 2 is correct.

Source: *The ILI English Series, Intermediate 1, Student's book, Page 101*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **deadly** in the phrase *deadly secrets* is often used figuratively, not literally, to mean a secret which would bring about someone's downfall if it were revealed. It would be a fatal blow to their reputation.

It can also be used to refer to something that threatens health over the long term. An article in a health magazine might be entitled *The Seven Deadly Secrets of Fast Food*

It can also be used literally, to mean "fatal".  *He received a deadly wound.*

Answer (score 1):

It's 1. A 'deadly secret' is one which if learned by the wrong people would lead to someone's death.

You can have a 'deadly silence' meaning 'complete silence', and there are phrases such as 'dead ahead', 'dead stop', 'dead on time' that mean completely/exactly/totally, but 'deadly' and 'completely' are not, in general, synonyms.

Comment: Then what do you think of _deadly secret_ in "Don’t say anything to anyone – this is meant to be a deadly secret"? Source: [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/deadly_1)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, deadly in 'deadly secrets' stands as life taking.

Deadly secrets: The secrets which can be fatal/cause death of person who come to know about it.

And about the options you gave, I'll choose 1.

I agree that, This again is dependent on usage of this phrase in sentence.